# Best solution for additional (dual) battery for E-bike

Tags: electric-bike, battery

I've marked a few possible places for additional battery mount.

What do you think is the most reliable place to mount battery in terms of ergonomics of the bike? Also, how to ensure the parts are having waterproof connection?

Model is OIO City Bike

Additional specs:

```
 Wheels diameter: 26 inches

 Motor: 350 Watt, brushless, maintenance-free

 Speed: 35 km / h

 Weight: 21 kg

 Load: 120 kg

 LCD Display (KBY-DISP KD21C): Indication of battery charge status, support level, speed

 Number of gears: 21

 Brakes: Disc

 Frame: Aluminum

 Battery: 36V 10.4Ah Li-ION
```

[image: bike scheme]

Comment: I do not understand your question.  Did you already solve the electrical engineering part? Do you want to carry there just as a spare or is it supposed to be connected to the motor? You can carry a spare anywhere you want. Is the main battery user-replaceable at all?

Comment: Please clarify this: *"However, it's unclear for me what would be the best solution to change between them since original battery is integrated into the downtube."* If you want us to tell how you swap batteries in your bike, we cannot know that, we do not have your bike.

Comment: There may be a trigger based activation, such as after main battery is certain %, it disconnected and spare battery is turning on, this option requres microcontoller. More simple is manual switch.

Comment: If you want us to propose a complete electrical engineering solution, you came to the wrong site, really. You also have to tell us much more information, we do not have your bike in front of us.

Comment: Not complete, just clues... like microcontoller to buy, some underwater stones on the way.. probably main part of the question is electical engineering, but it's all regarding bike reliability and safety anyway

Comment: The only part here about a bicycle is how to mount your additional battery in a safe way.  All the electrical work is really irrelevant that its on a bicycle.   Do you intend to charge the extra battery separately?  Or do you simply want to make the bike believe it has a single, larger capacity battery ?

Comment: And also remember that you have an infinite secondary battery, in that its a pedal powered bicycle.  If the main battery runs flat, just pedal like normal.  Its not a motorbike - its an electric *assisted* bicycle.

Comment: @Criggie I agree, however this bike has full throttle option as well as pedal assistance. And intention here is to drive relatively long distances in one day.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because its about the electronics to switch between battery packs and not about bicycles

Comment: @AndyP Let me reformulate the question...

Comment: The size & shape of the battery would factor in.  E.g. can it be attached at a water bottle cage?  Specialized does this ... the S-Works Turbo Creo SL and Turbo Vado SL both have an option to attach a spare battery on the bottle cage mount.  e.g. https://www.specialized.com/us/en/turbo-creo-sl

Comment: @TimCampbell That looks like pretty good look-ahead decision to do design this way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to assume that the question is:
**Where is the best place to put an extra battery that will:**
**- Optimize weight distribution**
**- Be out of the way / not interfere with general bike operation**

All three areas you have identified as options are used on touring bikes to store luggage and are reasonably interference free.
The two options inside the front triangle make sense because those locations tend to distribute the weight of the battery to both wheels.
Having an extra battery on a rack over the rear wheel will put all of the weight on the rear wheel only and it will take up space that could be used to carry other things.

I recommend mocking up something inexpensive that mimics the size and weight of the spare battery and trying it in different places. You may need to make a couple of mock ups but experimentation is the best way to learn.
When you have found the best location, size, shape and how to attach it for your use case you can spend money on actual hardware and know what you need.